# I need to select multiple SPAN elements

Tags: javascript, html

On my web page I want to 'hide' or 'unhide' several elements (C and F in this example) that are already inside a DIV element, 
such as:

```
<div> Select A or B <span name='hide' > or C</span></div>
<div> Also select D or E <span name='hide' > or F</span></div>
(etc)
```

I use javascript to hide all 'hide' elements when the page is opened, except when the page is opened on localhost, than all is shown.
I do not necessarily know how many 'hide' elements there are (dynamically generated).

```
var hids=document.getElementsByName('hide');
if(hids!=null) {
    for(var j=0; j< hids.length; j++) {
        if(localhost==true) { // only if on localhost
            hids[j].style.visibility='visible';
        }
        else hids[j].style.visibility='hidden';
    }
}
```

But, the 'name' attribute is not valid for SPAN. When  I use DIV instead of SPAN it messes up the format. How should I solve this properly?

Answer (score 2):

Use `class` instead of `name`:

```
<span class="my-class"> or C</span>
```

and `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementsByName`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
```

Answer (score 2):

If span doesn't have a name attribute, try with class name

```
var hids=document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
```

And change your html to

```
<div> Select A or B <span class='hide' > or C</span></div>
<div> Also select D or E <span class='hide' > or F</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to find by className `hide`

```js
var localhost = false;
var hids = document.querySelectorAll('.hide');

if (hids != null) {
  for (var j = 0; j < hids.length; j++) {
    if (localhost) { // only if on localhost
      hids[j].style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else hids[j].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```html
<div> Select A or B <span class='hide'> or C</span></div>
<div> Also select D or E <span class='hide'> or F</span></div>
(etc)
```

## Resource

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: I like the queryselectorAll, as I can do `var hids = document.querySelectorAll('span.hide');`  . Still don't understand why 'name' is not valid as it seems an obvious way to select multiple elements. Thanks for answering to all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-XXX` attribute instead of `name`, e.g.: `<span data-name='hide'>`

For sure, in this case, you will need to fetch them like this:

`document.getElementsByTagName("data-name")` and do another filtering based on the value of the `data-name` tag.

Comment: I immediately thought to go to className... but reading your answer makes me think I like via data- attribute better. Now I'm stuck wondering; Are they functionally equivalent in this situation?

Comment: I believe the result is the same, it just adds some more semantics to your HTML. Using classes is the main-stream, but it is good to know that you have the data-* attributes and it is safe to use them, because it is valid in all browsers (i think).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure the `name` property should be used here. I believe names are intended to be unique. So instead maybe through class name;

```
let localhost = true;
let hideList = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");

if (hideList != null) {
  for (var j=0; j < hideList.length; j++ ) {
    if (localhost === true) {
  hideList[j].style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
      hideList[j].style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
  }
}
```

As for the `<div>` messing up your formatting; thats likely due to a style property: `display`. `<span>`'s behave like `display: inline;` while `<div>`'s behave like `display: block;`. You can override this default behavior in your own CSS. Go ahead and turn those `<spans>`'s into `<div>`'s and apply some CSS:

```
<div> Select A or B <div class="hide"> or C</div></div>
<div> Also select D or E <div class="hide"> or F</div></div>

<style>
  .hide {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>
```

The result should be visually identical to when using spans.